# "xcodebuild test" keeps breaking my info.plist file

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xcodebuild

I am trying to test my Unity application on a simulator from command line but when I try to do it, the info.plist file is broken by xcodebuild test.

Here is how I try to do it :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

xcodebuild \
    -project "Tests.ios/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj" \
    -scheme "Unity-iPhone" \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    -derivedDataPath Tests \
    -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11,OS=13.4" \
    test

ENABLE_BITCODE=NO
```

The error I get is this one :

```
Testing failed:
Unity-iPhone Tests:
tests.app encountered an error (Failed to install or launch the test runner. (Underlying error: Failed to install the requested application. The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.))
```

When I look in the info.plist after the xcodebuild test, there is only two lines :

```
LastAccessedDate
WorkspacePath
```

The info.plist was correct before the xcodebuild.

When I try to do it directly from xcode (Product => Test, with the simulator), it succeeds perfectly.
However, when I try to do it directly from xcode after trying to do it with xcodebuild, it fails with the same error than xcodebuild.

Does someone knows how to get rid of this error ?